# how to make a function that checks a list of 20 digits

Tags: python

So i currently have a function that generates at random 20 digits shown below. Now i need to create another function that takes the first functions 20 digit number and counts the number of 0's within it. So far i have my first function:

What are my first steps into creating a function that counts the amount of 0's within the first function. I know i have to pass (random_number) over to my function as a parameter and then maybe a while loop to count the number of 0's?

Thanks for your help!

```
import random

def random_digits(n):

    range_start = 10**(n-1)
    range_end = (10**n)-1
    random_number= random.randint (range_start, range_end)
    print (random_number)

random_digits(20)
```

Comment: 100% correct to some extent. Its not an assignment its just something id like to know if asked such question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to count the number of a specific character appears in a string (after converting your 20-digit number to string):

```
import random
def random_digits(n):
  range_start = 10**(n-1)
  range_end = (10**n)-1
  random_number= random.randint (range_start, range_end)
  print(random_number)
  return (random_number)

def countzeros(n):
  print(len([c for c in str(n) if c == '0']))

countzeros(random_digits(20))
```

which e.g. returns:

```
22031776701742051347
3
```

Comment: ahhh i get it, all i had to do was convert it into str format then print the length of the list of 0's. Although, there is still an error at the last print statement for the (len) function that says (expected one of <new line>.

Comment: well, that's one way to do it I'm sure there are many others, this is what hit me first

Comment: are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: currently using python 3

Comment: give it a go now, this works for both python 2&3 on my machine

Answer (score 2):

```
def zeros(num):
    return str(num).count('0')

print zeros(random_digits(20))
```

Another way could be this:

```
def zeros(num):
    ctr = 0
    while num > 0:
        if num % 10 == 0:
            ctr += 1
        num = num/10
    return ctr
```